# Alphabet Index in ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter very slow

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to implement the Alphabet-Index in ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter. 
It is working but it is very slow, when i am trying to scroll the list up and down the phone is getting strucked. I think its is happening because of my way of coding due to lack of knowledge. so that I need to know what is the mistake or what is the wrong of this code. And also if there is any other way than this way, please let me know.

This is set of code of fragment which has the above problem.

```
public class EnFragment extends Fragment {

    private TestAdapter dbHelper;
    private myCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    public EnFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dbHelper = new TestAdapter(getContext());
        dbHelper.createDatabase();
        dbHelper.open();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_en, container, false);
        setListView(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setListView(View view) {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllWord("enDic");

        String[] columns = new String[]{
                "word",
                "definition",
                "_id",
                "favourite"
        };

        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.txt_word,
                R.id.txt_def,
                R.id.txt_id
        };

        dataAdapter = new myCursorAdapter(
                getContext(), en_word_row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        Button btnSubmitEng = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitEng);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listView.setEmptyView(btnSubmitEng);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), word, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void textSearch(String searchTxt){
        String newStr = searchTxt.replace(" ","");
        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newStr);

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.getWordByName("enDic",constraint.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private class myCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

        private final AlphabetIndexer mAlphabetIndexer;

        public myCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, 
                               Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
            mAlphabetIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, 1, "අBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        }

        public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return inflater.inflate(en_word_row, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

            final ImageButton imgFav = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.img_fav);
            final String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            final Integer fav = Integer
                    .valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite")));

            if (fav == 1)
                imgFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_on);
            else
                imgFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_off);

            imgFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (dbHelper.isFavourite("enDic", _id)){
                        imgFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_off);
                        dbHelper.favUpdate("enDic", _id,0);
                    }
                    else{
                        imgFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_on);
                        dbHelper.favUpdate("enDic", _id,1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getSections() {
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getSections();
        }

        @Override
        public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getPositionForSection(sectionIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            return mAlphabetIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_en.xml (layout of the above fragment)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sldroid.mecdic_v21.fragment.EnFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit new word"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmitEng"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

en_word_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_word"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Word"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#424242"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_def"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="definition"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FF757575"
                    android:lines="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/img_fav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fav_off"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

method of TestAdapter

```
public Cursor getAllWord(String table)
{
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(table, new String[] {"_id","word","definition","favourite"},
            null, null, null,null, " word COLLATE NOCASE");

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor getWordByName(String table, String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(table, new String[] {"_id","word","definition","favourite"},
                null, null, null,null, " word COLLATE NOCASE");

    }
    else {
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, table, new String[] {"_id","word","definition","favourite"},
                "word" + " like '" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, " word COLLATE NOCASE",null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: You are doing all the work in main thread, you should use async task to make db calls. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás I have already used AsyncTask for Internet service.. but I have not any idea how AsyncTask use for db calls. So please can you provide some example.

Answer (score 0):

GetAllWord and getWordByName should be called in the doInBackground method and in the postExecute you shoul update your adapter.

```
private class GetAllWord extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return GetAllWord("your text");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        if (result != null) {
            //update the adapter with the result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created GetAllWord AsyncTask. but i haven't any idea about where and how i used "new GetAllWord().excute();" command.. please can you help me?

Comment: Yes, and you have to pass "your text" as parameter. You make the call when you want to execture, for example in OnClickListener of the button.

Comment: In my fragment I created Cursor variable and dbHelper.getAllWord("enDic"); is assigned to previously created cursor and then I created myCursorAdapter object and it used cursor variable.. My problem is how i used AsyncTask for myCursorAdapter ?

Comment: Call the asyntask in onCreateView and in the method onPostExecute of async task you update myCursorAdapter with the result.

Comment: I set the myCursorAdapter as the result variable type of the AsyncTask and then I created the myCursorAdapter object in doInBackground method and return adapter. after that I used "listView.setAdapter(result);"  code in onPostExecute method. is it correct? It's work but listView get more time to update after application load